# Rails: "bundle install" failed because of old rails version(3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I recently got a old Rails application and trying to install gems through `bundle install`. But it keeps reminding me :

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": In Gemfile:rails (~> 3.2) was resolved to 3.2.22.5, which depends on bundler (~> 1.0)

After some google search, I get to know that rails 3.2 freezes bundler version at 1.0. So I uninstalled my current bundler(2.0.1) by doing `gem uninstall bundler -v 2.0.1`and install bundler 1.0.10`gem install bundler -v 1.0.10```, but another error occurs:

> /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': 
>   undefined method`source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
>   Did you mean?  sources
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:195:in `default_gemfile'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:165:in`root'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:171:in `app_config_path'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:183:in`settings'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in`run'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in`dispatch'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in`'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
>       from /home/alec/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/bundle:22:in`'

BTW, my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://gems.ruby-china.com'

unless RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /w32/
  # unix-like only
  gem 'iconv'
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
    gem "rmagick", "= 2.15.4" ## osx must be this version
  elsif RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
    gem 'simple_xlsx_reader'
    gem "rmagick", "~> 2.13.1" ## centos yum install ImageMagick-devel
    gem 'pdfkit'
    gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
    gem 'rqrcode', '~> 0.10.1'
    gem 'rqrcode_png'
  end
  gem 'certified'
  gem 'net-ssh', '2.9.1'
  gem 'jenkins_api_client'
  gem 'nokogiri'
end

#gem 'simple_xlsx_reader'
gem 'wechat',path: 'lib/wechat'
gem 'grack', path:'lib/grack'
gem 'gitlab', path: 'lib/gitlab-cli'
gem 'rest-client'
gem "mysql2", "= 0.3.18"
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'#, :group => :production
gem 'daemons'
gem 'grape', '~> 0.9.0'
gem 'grape-entity', '= 0.4.5'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'seems_rateable', '~> 1.0.13'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2'
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.2"
gem "i18n", "~> 0.6.0"
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.1.0'
gem "fastercsv", "~> 1.5.0", :platforms => [:mri_18, :mingw_18, :jruby]
gem "builder", "3.0.0"
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.4.1'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'ruby-ole'
gem 'rails_kindeditor',path:'lib/rails_kindeditor'
gem 'binding_of_caller'
gem 'chinese_pinyin'
# gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.3.3'
# gem 'sunspot_solr'
# gem 'sunspot'
# gem 'progress_bar'
gem  'ansi'

gem 'kaminari'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'

#rails 3.2.22.2 bug
# gem "test-unit", "~>3.0"

### profile
# gem 'oneapm_rpm'
# gem 'therubyracer'

group :development do
  gem 'grape-swagger'
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 1.1.0'
  # gem "query_reviewer"
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 0.9.3'
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /w32/
    gem  'win32console'
  end

  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
    gem 'puma'
end
end

group :development, :test do
    if RUBY_VERSION >= '2.0.0'
      gem 'pry-byebug'
    gem "test-unit", "~>3.0"
    end
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
  gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.3.1"
end


# Optional gem for OpenID authentication
group :openid do
  gem "ruby-openid", "~> 2.1.4", :require => "openid"
  gem "rack-openid"
end


database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")
if File.exist?(database_file)
else
  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/Gemfile", __FILE__) do |file|
  puts "Loading #{file} ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`
  instance_eval File.read(file)
end
```

I have searched everywhere but nothing useful. Any help would highly appreciated!Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there's some incompatibility between an old version of `bundler` and `rubygems`.

I was able to successfully install your `Gemfile` by updating `bundler` (In this snippet I'm updating it to latest available v1):

```sh
$ gem uninstall bundler
$ gem install bundler -v '~>1'
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Amazing! It works, can you give me some related documentation about this option `'~>1'` ?

Comment: @Talon.Zhou it's the same syntax you used in your `Gemfile`, like `gem 'grape', '~> 0.9.0'`, the `'~> 0.9.0'` part. Here's the full syntax for the version field: https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#pessimistic-version-constraint

Comment: Really appreciate your help!